# xcode command line tools not able to locate git

Tags: command-line-tool, xcode-command-line-tools

On Big Sur, I had XCode CLT installed, but not xcode itself.  Git was working fine.
Then I installed XCode and now when I try to run git I get the following message:

```
git: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
git: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'git', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

A popup comes up, asks to install CLT and when I say ok, it downloads and installs for a few minutes.  But when it's done, I'm right back where I started.
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk` does not exist, but there are directories for `10.15`, `11.1` and `11.3`.  But not `10.14`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Run the command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Worked again on the recent security patch for macOS 12.6 and Xcode 14.

Comment: Perfect. Just now installed Ventura, works like a charm!!

Comment: Can you explain why this works? It's always a good practice to understand what we run on our computers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience. The solution was to launch Xcode and complete that first run. It downloaded some stuff as part of the process and `git` was fine after that.

I was receiving the same block of error messages you were, but in either the line above or below was a tidbit suggesting to run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` which I suspect would have had the same effect as manually running Xcode that first time.